# Read all files in a directory and determine if they return True or False for any conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, wildcard

I have a python script where I'm trying to read all .txt files in a directory and determine if they return True or False for any conditions that are in my script. If you go down to line 14 you can see that I'm trying to setup my code so that it will loop through and pickup all files ending in .txt. Every file name in the directory is different so I'm trying to implement a wildcard format. Your help is very much appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import json
import pprint
import sys


CSVPATH = 'CsvResults.csv'
VTOUTPUTPATH = './output/'
VTOUTPUTEXT = '.txt'
**vt_result_path = VTOUTPUTPATH + glob.glob('dir/*') + VTOUTPUTEXT**
#vt_result = vt_result_check(vt_result_path)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)


# Check files from VirusTotal queries for any positive results
# Result is false unless any nonzero positive result is true
def vt_result_check(vt_result_path):
    vt_result = None
    try:
        vt_result = False
        with open(vt_result_path) as vt_result_file:
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

            # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_referrer_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_communicating_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_downloaded_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected URLs
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_urls']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
            try:
                if (vt_data['Dr.Web category'] == "known infection source"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "elevated exposure"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "phishing and other frauds"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "suspicious content"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            #pp.pprint(vt_data)
    except:
        pass
    return vt_result



def cert_check(csvpath):
    with open(csvpath, 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['vt_result']
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(['VirusTotal Results'])
        vt_result_path = VTOUTPUTPATH + subject_dom + VTOUTPUTEXT
        vt_result = vt_result_check(vt_result_path)
        writer.writerow([vt_result])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir(directoryname)` to get a list of filenames in the directory, and you can essentially filter that list for files with the extension '.txt' by using string slicing and list comprehension. For example:

```
files_to_search = [f for f in os.listdir(directoryname) if f[-4:] == '.txt']
```

will return a list of filenames that end in '.txt' (assuming all filenames are at least four characters long).

Comment: Thank you for your response! If I want to read in the .txt files as a loop to parse through the contents of each .txt file, how would I best do that?

Comment: Just use a `for` loop, iterating over that list. Inside the loop, put all the code you want to execute on that specific file. e.g., `for file in files_to_search: ...`

Answer (score 0):

I made another list, and I added the elements if the condition is not True. then I printed the new list. NOW it works properly.

```
lis2=[]
```

lis3=[]
if **name** == '**main**':
x = int(input())`
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

```
   for i in range(x+1):
       #print(i)
   for j in range(y+1):
        #print(j)
        for k in range(z+1):
            #print(k)
            lis2.append([i,j,k])
#print(lis2)
for [i,j,k] in lis2:
    #print([i,j,k])
    #print(i+j+k==n)
    if not  i+j+k==n:
        #print([i,j,k])
        #print(i+j+k==n)
        lis3.append([i,j,k])
print(lis3)
```